# Why do I get the error “Missing number, treated as zero”?

Tags: tables

I am currently defining a custom list environment for my CV. After significant help by this community, I managed to get the list environment as desired and it worked like a charm. However, compiling now generates an error. I am quite shocked, because I haven’t changed anything since the last successful compilation (at least, not knowingly. Hence, I’m at a complete loss at what is causing the error. The error that I get is “ Missing number, treated as zero”. The following MWE replicates the error.

```
\documentclass{article}
    
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\pagestyle{empty}
      
\newenvironment{entrylist}{%
  \noindent
  \begin{tabular*}{}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}rl}
}{%
  \end{tabular*}
}
\renewcommand{\bfseries}{}
\newcommand{\entry}[4]{%
    \parbox[t]{2cm}{#1\raggedleft}&\parbox[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-2cm}{\strut%
    \textbf{#2}%
    \hfill%
    {\footnotesize #3\par}\\%
    #4\vspace{\parsep}%
  }\\}
  

\begin{document}
    
\begin{entrylist}
    
\entry
   {Office}
   {A very fancy building in a very fancy place}
   {}
   {}
  
\entry
   {Website}
   {www.somename.com}
   {}
   {}
    
 \entry
   {Email}
   {somename a aaa}
   {}
   {}
   
 \entry
   {Phone}
   {+00 0000 000000}
   {}
   {}
  
\end{entrylist}
    
\end{document}
```

Any help and finding and correcting the culprit of the error will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you all very much in advance for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are *two* errors in your code.

- The first argument of the `tabular*` environment must not be empty. Instead, it has got to be a usable, i.e., positive length. Hence, I suggest you replace

  ```
  \begin{tabular*}{}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}rl}
  ```

  with

  ```
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}rl}
  ```

  Actually, the contents of the columns are hard-coded to be fixed-width `\parbox` entitities. Hence, the `tabular*` machinery does absolutely nothing useful. Thus, just write

  ```
  \newenvironment{entrylist}{%
    \noindent
    \begin{tabular}{@{}rl@{}}
  }{%
    \end{tabular}
  }
  ```
- Second, there shouldn't be a `\\` (line-break) directive in

  ```
  {\footnotesize #3\par}\\%
  ```

  since `\par` already produces a line-break.

---

To summarize, I think you may want to define the environment `entrylist` and the macro `\entry` as follows:

```
\newenvironment{entrylist}{%
  \noindent
  \begin{tabular}{@{} r l @{}}}{%
  \end{tabular}}

\newcommand{\entry}[4]{%
    \parbox[t]{2cm}{#1\raggedleft} &
    \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-2cm\relax}{\strut%
    #2%
    \hfill%
    {\footnotesize #3\par}
    #4\vspace{\parsep}%
  }\\}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please further elaborate what my mistakes are?

Comment: @Héctor - Sorry, I hit "save" too soon, by accident, before I finished the answer. I've now edited and expanded my answer.

Comment: Your answer is excellent —thank you very much for your kind help.